# finditem() doesn't find menu, stuck with NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I'm stuck while changing some properties on my options menu at `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. It seems like findItem() returns null, even though I'm pretty sure that the reference to the menu item is correct. My code looks as follows:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_profile, menu);
        MenuItem leftie = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_profile);
        leftie.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_mapmode);
        leftie.setTitle(R.string.back_map);
        leftie.setIntent(authIntent);

        return true;
    }
```

I really don't know what can be wrong there. Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: I forgot to include the actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mention title and image for that menu item in XML.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/newsItem"
    android:icon="@drawable/news_tab"
    android:title="@string/menu_news"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/dryiceItem"
    android:icon="@drawable/dryice_tab"
    android:title="@string/menu_dryice"/>

</menu>
```

and can set intent on menuItem like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.newsItem:
        // start News activity
        //write your intent here.
        break;
    case R.id.dryiceItem:
                   //start another activity
                   //write your intent here.
         break; 
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The String that references to the `menu` index, `R.menu.activity_profile` was the wrong path so it was inflating an empty menu. I changed the string to `R.menu.layout` and now it works as expected.

```
System.out.println(menu.size());
MenuItem leftie = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_profile);
System.out.println(leftie);
leftie.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_mapmode);
leftie.setTitle(R.string.back_map);
leftie.setIntent(authIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this happen when I had a submenu that wasn't properly nested in item tags, like

```
<item />
    <menu>
    </menu>
```

or

```
    <item >
        <menu>
        </menu>
   <item>
```

Answer (score -1):

Typecast your findItem statement with MenuItem

```
         MenuItem leftie = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_profile);
```