# SetMenuItem returning nullpointer exception

Tags: java, android, material-design, searchview

I have a toolbar that returns nullpointer exception for my Material Searchview icon.

This is my method to return searchview items

```
MaterialSearchView searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Do some magic
            String clubName = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //double latitude = Double.parseDouble(item.);
            Club selectedClub = getClub(clubName);
            PlotMarker(selectedClub.getLat(), selectedClub.getLng());
            address.setText(selectedClub.getAddress());
            description.setText(selectedClub.getDesc());
            name.setText(selectedClub.getName1());
            Log.i("TAG", "http://partygoer.org"+selectedClub.getImage());
            Picasso.with(MapActivity.this).load("http://partygoer.org"+selectedClub.getImage()).into(imageClub);
        }
    });
```

Below is where i select the menu item

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    **searchView.setMenuItem(item);**

    return true;
}
```

And this is my xml, the setMenuItem returns null pointer exception

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

    <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

this is the error log

```
 01-20 07:54:05.564 14209-14209/com.lawerh.jonathan.partygoer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.lawerh.jonathan.partygoer, PID: 14209
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView.setMenuItem(android.view.MenuItem)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.lawerh.jonathan.partygoer.ui.MapActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MapActivity.java:122)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2889)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:362)
                                                                               at android.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:76)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:447)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:55)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
```

Comment: please post the error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946379/finditem-doesnt-find-menu-stuck-with-nullpointerexception

Comment: @PhanVanLinh i have updated my question with the error

Comment: Since this is working during the `setOnItemClickListener` you either have set it to null or are working with a different variable. Well depending on when `MaterialSearchView searchView =(MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);` is done